# Can we export HBase data from CDH3 and import it into CDH5 HBase?

Tags: hadoop, hbase, cloudera-cdh

We have a old CDH3 based cluster and we have data stored in HBase on this cluster. We also have brand new cluster in which CDH5.2 is installed.

We want to move HBase data from CDH3 cluster to CDH5 cluster. I would like to know if it is possible to migrate data across different versions? Is it straight forward like using `distcp` command?

What precautions I need to take before migrating data and during migration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there is a simple solution for this. The simplest solution I can think of is to use one MapReduce job to export each HBase table to HDFS on your CDH3 cluster. One DistCp job to transfer exported HDFS data from your CDH3 cluster to HDFS on CDH5 cluster, then finally one MapReduce job for each table to import the HDFS data into Hbase.

You can export tables from HBase to HDFS by using the default IdentityTableMapper with no reducer. Set the KEY, VALUE to ImmutableBytesWriable, org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.Result and the output format class as SequenceFileOutputFormat. Basically this will write out whatever data in a HBase table to SequenceFile files, preserving the format as you would read it directly from HBase.

On the import side on your CDH5 cluster after DistCp, use this mapper class which read data from the exported files and write them to a HBase table.

```
public class HbaseSequenceFileToTableMapper extends TableMapper<ImmutableBytesWritable, Put>{
@Override
public void map(ImmutableBytesWritable row, Result value, Context context)
        throws IOException {
    try {
        context.write(row, resultToPut(row, value));
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

private static Put resultToPut(ImmutableBytesWritable key, Result result)
        throws IOException {
    Put put = new Put(key.get());
    for (KeyValue kv : result.raw()) {
        put.add(kv);
    }
    return put;
}
}
```

This solution works great if you have to transfer a lot of data from your old cluster to your new cluster.